# Is processing a dead project?

Tags: python

Look at the last updated release, Python 2.5??

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/processing

Comment: Why vote to close? It's not obvious, there's not even a link on the old processing page is there?

Comment: To be clear, this is different than this [pyprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It became](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0371/) [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).